# Download file from server to client using ASP.NET and C# does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, webclient

I'm trying to create grid in ASP where I can download files to the client's side using code behind.
I want that after a button is pressed the user will see options to save or open the file on his PC.

This is my code to download the file:

```
string link = txtLink.Text;

WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] data = client.DownloadData(new Uri(link));

Response.Clear();

string[] pathArr = link.Split('/');
string fileName = pathArr[pathArr.Length - 1].ToString();

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Response.End();
```

The code runs well and does not fall, but nothing is happening on the client's side. the file does not appear.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `link` and how long is the byte array? If you can answer both those questions in debug you are a lot closer to solving the problem,  because it works when I tested it with an actual `http://` url and a fixed filename.

Comment: The link is the link to a file on our servers, when I put it in the URL of the browser I can see the file. the file is about 400 KB in size so this is not the issue.